# How to use multiple CSS classes in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

In react.js I want to use a css style like this

```
<button class = "btn btn-primary"> A Button </ button>
import style1 from './style.css'
return <button className = {s['btn btn-primary']}> A Button </ button>;
```

How do I do it?

Comment: <button className = {'btn btn-primary'}> A Button </ button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can just simply place the classes as a string, like this:

```
<button className="btn btn-primary"> A Button </ button>
```

or if you have complex classes with logic, you can use this great package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
<button className={classNames({ foo: true, bar: false })}> A Button </button>
```

this will result to this html:

```
<button class="foo"> A Button </button>
```